# Dynamically implement method by composition (like decorator in kotlin)

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, composition

I am using Python, and I have an interface (a class that only defines the methods signature), that is implemented by two other classes. Now I am adding another wrapper class that implement the interface/base-class, but is actually getting one of the other classes and this wrapper class in most cases just calls one of the two classes. I would like to do some Python magic to avoid defining all methods only the one that I really change.

Here is an example:

```
class SomeInterface(object):
    def do_1(self):
        raise Exception("please implement")

    def do_2(self):
        raise Exception("please implement")

    def do_3(self):
        raise Exception("please implement")


class Goo(SomeInterface):
    def do_1(self):
        print("I am goo 1")

    def do_2(self):
        print("I am goo 2")

    def do_3(self):
        print("I am goo 3")

class Foo(SomeInterface):
    def do_1(self):
        print("I am foo 1")

    def do_2(self):
        print("I am foo 2")

    def do_3(self):
        print("I am foo 3")


class WrappingInterface(SomeInterface):
    def __init__(self, inf: SomeInterface):
        self._inner = inf

    def do_1(self):
        self._inner.do_1()

    def do_2(self):
        self._inner.do_2()

    def do_3(self):
        self._inner.do_2()
        print("And then doing something else")
```

Basically, instead of writing do_1 and do_2 in the wrapper class, I would like to do some magic and be able to only write the relevant code.

I tried to implement it using Mixin, but it did not work. Maybe decorator can do it, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why do you want to do it like that way. You can inherit your `WrappingInterface` from the child class (Eg.: from `Foo`):

**Code:**

```
class WrappingInterface(Foo):

    def do_3(self):
        super().do_3()
        print("And then doing something else")


test = WrappingInterface()
test.do_1()
test.do_2()
test.do_3()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
I am foo 1
I am foo 2
I am foo 3
And then doing something else
```

But if you really needed to extend the base classes then you can do it like this:

**Dynamically extend base classes:**

```
class WrappingInterface(SomeInterface):
    def __init__(self, inf: SomeInterface):
        self._inner = inf

    def do_3(self):
        self._inner.do_3()
        print("And then doing something else")


WrappingInterface = type("WrappingInterface", (Foo,), dict(WrappingInterface.__dict__))
test = WrappingInterface(Foo())
test.do_1()
test.do_2()
test.do_3()
```

**Output:**

```
> python3 test.py 
I am foo 1
I am foo 2
I am foo 3
And then doing something else
```

Or you can do everything inside your class (It's a little hacky but it works).

**Code:**

```
class WrappingInterface(SomeInterface):
    def __init__(self, inf: SomeInterface):
        self._inner = inf()
        methods = [method for method in dir(inf) if not method.startswith('__')
                   and callable(getattr(inf, method))]
        for method in methods:
            if method in self.__class__.__dict__:
                continue
            setattr(WrappingInterface, method, getattr(inf, method))

    def do_3(self):
        self._inner.do_3()
        print("And then doing something else")


test = WrappingInterface(Foo)
test.do_1()
test.do_2()
test.do_3()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
I am foo 1
I am foo 2
I am foo 3
And then doing something else
```

**Note:**

I recommend to check the `Abstract Base Classes` in Python to do a "real" Abstraction. Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

Comment: Thank you milanbalazs, I was looking for the last solution. just one more question, does this pattern has a name?

Comment: You are welcome! Yeah, it's a pattern, if a method starts with double underscore then it will be filtered out (Eg.: `__init__` or `__eq__`). BUT I have been thinking about it and I would use the `endswith` instead of `startswith` because if your interface class contains private methods (eg.: `__foo()`) then they will be filtered out. But your own methods won't be ended with double underscore (eg.: `foo__()`) so I guess the `endswith` is more efficient.